# Laravel Route : route::resource

Tags: laravel, routes, resources

I'm very new in laravel,
I'm following some tutorial

this code work fine

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::resource('tes', 'TesController');
});
<form action="{{ route('tes.destroy',3) }}" method="post">
```

until i modified it like this one

```
Route::resource('tes/keren', 'TesController');

<form action="{{ route('tes/keren.destroy',3) }}" method="post">
```

It said tes/keren.destroy undefined....
just simple question, which should I modify so, I can route with /

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Route::resource('url/resource-route','ResouceControllerName')` takes the **last segment** as a resource name & then automatically build the routes for it.

when you use `Route::resource('tes', 'TesController');` it build the routes for **tes** resource (like *tes.store*, t*es.create*, *tes.destroy*, etc)

But when your change your route to this  `Route::resource('tes/keren', 'TesController');`

It binds all the routes to **keren** resource.

So use this in your blade file.

```
<form action="{{ route('keren.destroy', 3) }}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

The `route` helper function takes the route name as the parameter. When you changed the route url, the route name changed to `keren.destroy` from `tes.destroy`. So you need to change your form action to

```
<form action="{{ route('keren.destroy', 3) }}" method="post">
```

If you ever want to check your route names, just run `php artisan route:list` from the terminal/console. In this case it should show you something like this.

```
| GET|HEAD  | tes/keren              | keren.index   | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@index   | web          |
| POST      | tes/keren              | keren.store   | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@store   | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | tes/keren/create       | keren.create  | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@create  | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | tes/keren/{keren}      | keren.show    | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@show    | web          |
| PUT|PATCH | tes/keren/{keren}      | keren.update  | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@update  | web          |
| DELETE    | tes/keren/{keren}      | keren.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@destroy | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | tes/keren/{keren}/edit | keren.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\TesController@edit    | web          |
```

Answer (score 0):

[`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route) helper uses route name to build URL, so you should do this instead:

```
<form action="{{ route('keren.destroy', 3) }}" method="post">
```

You can see all available routes and route names with this command:

```
php artisan route:list
```